# What is the name of this part? Marking: 2RVD

Tags: mosfet, identification, markings, sot23

I wondered what this part is. The package is SOT-23 3PIN and the marking is 2RVD and I think it is a MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: Could it possibly be [FMMT5210 NPN transistor](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/115/fmmt5209-1164695.pdf)?  How old is the circuit, what else is around this part?

Comment: Or perhaps [SRA2202 PNP transistor with biasing resistors](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/77822/AUK/SRA2202U.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markings match with a [Vishay Si2302DDS](https://www.vishay.com/docs/63653/si2302dds.pdf) N-channel MOSFET.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [aliexpress.ru](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005005665705888.html?sku_id=12000033945679163))

Comment: Thank you a lot , i was searching for half a day with wrong marking , It fits perfectly in the circuit that i had .